# Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Tags: list, google-maps, flutter, dart, google-polyline

I am trying to create path between two location on map and I am getting the markers on the correct position but path is not drawn due to this error.

```
setPolylines() async 
{   
  List<PointLatLng> result = await
    polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      googleAPIKey,
      SOURCE_LOCATION.latitude, 
      SOURCE_LOCATION.longitude,
      DEST_LOCATION.latitude, 
      DEST_LOCATION.longitude
    );   

    if(result.isNotEmpty){      
      result.forEach((PointLatLng point){
        polylineCoordinates.add(
          LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
      });
    }

    setState(() {
      Polyline polyline = Polyline(
        polylineId: PolylineId("poly"),
        color: Color.fromARGB(255, 40, 122, 198),
        points: polylineCoordinates
      );
      _polylines.add(polyline);    
    });
}
```

> Unhandled Exception: Exception: RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

How am I suppose to fix this?

Comment: did you found any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 await
    polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates(
      googleAPIKey,
      SOURCE_LOCATION.latitude, 
      SOURCE_LOCATION.longitude,
      DEST_LOCATION.latitude, 
      DEST_LOCATION.longitude
    ).then((result){

if(result.isNotEmpty){      
  result.forEach((PointLatLng point){
    polylineCoordinates.add(
      LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude));
  });
}

setState(() {
  Polyline polyline = Polyline(
    polylineId: PolylineId("poly"),
    color: Color.fromARGB(255, 40, 122, 198),
    points: polylineCoordinates
  );
  _polylines.add(polyline);    
});
   });
```

Comment: No, it didn't worked. It is throwing same Exception. Sorry, for the late reply.

Comment: Can you add results.toString() output?

Comment: Yes sure!! But where should I add result.toString() , because it throws Exception at `polylinePoints.getRouteBetweenCoordinates` and I added after that then it is not printing.

Comment: Did you make sure you are creating object successfully(PolylinePoints polylinePoints = PolylinePoints();) and placing right googleapikey ?

Comment: Yes I checked both of the things and I also checked on dashboard of Directions API it is showing me that hit is made but it failed

Answer (score 0):

The error is probably because of not enabling Directions API on your Google console, in my case i also had to set up my billing after enabling it to get the route to show. You can also make use of the $300 free trial credit.

Answer (score -1):

You are getting this error because `{
    "error_message": "This API project is not authorized to use this API.",
    "routes": [],
    "status": "REQUEST_DENIED"
}`

Make sure to enable the maps api.

Comment: How did you know that he is getting this error ? When he didn't mention anywhere !!!